# A QDateTimeEdit with a custom QCalendarWidget that intercepts mouse clicks?

Tags: qt, pyside

According to the [PySide docs](https://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QDateTimeEdit.html#detailed-description):

> `QDateTimeEdit` can be configured to allow a `QCalendarWidget` to be used to select dates. This is enabled by setting the `QDateTimeEdit.calendarPopup()` property. Additionally, you can supply a custom calendar widget for use as the calendar pop-up by calling the `QDateTimeEdit.setCalendarWidget()` function. The existing calendar widget can be retrieved with `QDateTimeEdit.calendarWidget()`.

Cool, I can do that, but my question is what are the uses for that? It doesn't appear that the custom calendar widget can intercept mouse clicks or paint events, which seems to me to be what you'd want to do with a customized calendar widget.  It's what I want to do, anyway.  I wrote a quick script to test this out:

```
from PySide.QtGui import *
from PySide.QtCore import *

import sys 

class EventLogger(QObject):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(EventLogger, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        print "Object = %s; event = %s" % (type(obj).__name__, event.type())
        return False

class MyCalendar(QCalendarWidget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyCalendar, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.installEventFilter(EventLogger(parent=self))
        print "*** Initializing custom calendar widget ***"

    def mousePressEvent(self, e): 
        print "*** Intercepting mouse press event ***"

class MyWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self._initUI()

        self.show()
        self.setFocus()
        self.raise_()

    def _initUI(self):
        layout = QGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)

        de = QDateTimeEdit()
        de.setCalendarPopup(True)
        de.setCalendarWidget(MyCalendar(parent=de))
        layout.addWidget(de, 0, 0, 1, 1)

def main():
    app = QApplication([])
    mw = MyWidget()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Running this, opening the calendar, clicking a date, and then exiting the program outputs:

```
*** Initializing custom calendar widget *** 
Object = MyCalendar; event = PySide.QtCore.QEvent.Type.ParentChange
Object = MyCalendar; event = PySide.QtCore.QEvent.Type.Polish
Object = MyCalendar; event = PySide.QtCore.QEvent.Type(70)
Object = MyCalendar; event = PySide.QtCore.QEvent.Type(70)
Object = MyCalendar; event = PySide.QtCore.QEvent.Type.ChildPolished
Object = MyCalendar; event = PySide.QtCore.QEvent.Type.ChildPolished
Object = MyCalendar; event = PySide.QtCore.QEvent.Type(67)
Object = MyCalendar; event = PySide.QtCore.QEvent.Type.PolishRequest
Object = MyCalendar; event = PySide.QtCore.QEvent.Type.LayoutRequest
Object = MyCalendar; event = PySide.QtCore.QEvent.Type.Move
Object = MyCalendar; event = PySide.QtCore.QEvent.Type.Resize
Object = MyCalendar; event = PySide.QtCore.QEvent.Type.Show
Object = MyCalendar; event = PySide.QtCore.QEvent.Type.ShowToParent
Object = MyCalendar; event = PySide.QtCore.QEvent.Type.LayoutRequest
Object = MyCalendar; event = PySide.QtCore.QEvent.Type.Enter
Object = MyCalendar; event = PySide.QtCore.QEvent.Type.Hide
Object = MyCalendar; event = PySide.QtCore.QEvent.Type.Leave
Object = QWidget; event = PySide.QtCore.QEvent.Type.DynamicPropertyChange
Object = QWidget; event = PySide.QtCore.QEvent.Type.ChildRemoved
```

This is notable for its lack of mouse click and paint events, and the `mousePressEvent()` function is not getting called.  So what's the easiest way to really customize this?  Am I going to have to re-implement the `QDateTimeEdit`/`QCalendarWidget` myself?  The docs say you can customize the calendar, but don't give any details on how to do it properly or even why you'd want to, given that it's apparently limited in what it can do in this context.

Comment: According to the [Qt Doc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qcalendarwidget.html#paintCell), you have a method `paintCell` to draw a date, and two signals `clicked` and `activated` for mouse events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, to answer my own question, the proper way to do this is *not* by intercepting mouse click and paint events, but using the [`paintCell()`](https://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QCalendarWidget.html#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QCalendarWidget.paintCell) method and the [`clicked`](https://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QCalendarWidget.html#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QCalendarWidget.clicked) signal, per tmoreau's comment. It's a little counter-intuitive, I guess, but the `paintCell()` method gives you rectangles for each day, which is handy.